# Display a list of sub-pages on the current page based on the WP menu

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a menu under Appearance > menus called "Sidebar Menu Collection"

This is their heirarchy

```
Material
- marble
- onyx
- slate
- granite

Applications
- benchtops
- floors
- walls

products
- Slab
- pavers
- cladding
```

So when I am on the page "Material" I would like to have a list of its child menu (marble,onyx,slate,grantite) only.

If I'm in "Applications" page it would show (benctops,floors,walls). And so on, I would like to add a featured image on every child list based on the page featured image.

Also this will be applicable only to the parent menu (Material,Applications,Products) and if your on the sub-menu no list will be shown

Answer (score 0):

Hello use below code will only show childs of specific pages

```
wp_list_pages( $args = '' ) {
    $defaults = array(
        'depth'        => 1,
        'show_date'    => '',
        'date_format'  => get_option( 'date_format' ),
        'child_of'     => $post->ID,
        'exclude'      => '',
        'title_li'     => __( 'Pages' ),
        'echo'         => 1,
        'authors'      => '',
        'sort_column'  => 'menu_order, post_title',
        'link_before'  => '',
        'link_after'   => '',
        'item_spacing' => 'preserve',
        'walker'       => '',
    );
```

Comment: They don't have parents, its only based on the menu structure, so like menu ancestor or something

Answer (score 0):

Already had an answer to this, came from this [post](https://christianvarga.com/how-to-get-submenu-items-from-a-wordpress-menu-based-on-parent-or-sibling/).

This is working perfectly, the only problem I have now is how to add a featured image on every link.

```
// add hook
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'my_wp_nav_menu_objects_sub_menu', 10, 2 );
// filter_hook function to react on sub_menu flag
function my_wp_nav_menu_objects_sub_menu( $sorted_menu_items, $args ) {
  if ( isset( $args->sub_menu ) ) {
    $root_id = 0;

    // find the current menu item
    foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $menu_item ) {
      if ( $menu_item->current ) {
        // set the root id based on whether the current menu item has a parent or not
        $root_id = ( $menu_item->menu_item_parent ) ? $menu_item->menu_item_parent : $menu_item->ID;
        break;
      }
    }

    // find the top level parent
    if ( ! isset( $args->direct_parent ) ) {
      $prev_root_id = $root_id;
      while ( $prev_root_id != 0 ) {
        foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $menu_item ) {
          if ( $menu_item->ID == $prev_root_id ) {
            $prev_root_id = $menu_item->menu_item_parent;
            // don't set the root_id to 0 if we've reached the top of the menu
            if ( $prev_root_id != 0 ) $root_id = $menu_item->menu_item_parent;
            break;
          } 
        }
      }
    }
    $menu_item_parents = array();
    foreach ( $sorted_menu_items as $key => $item ) {
      // init menu_item_parents
      if ( $item->ID == $root_id ) $menu_item_parents[] = $item->ID;
      if ( in_array( $item->menu_item_parent, $menu_item_parents ) ) {
        // part of sub-tree: keep!
        $menu_item_parents[] = $item->ID;
      } else if ( ! ( isset( $args->show_parent ) && in_array( $item->ID, $menu_item_parents ) ) ) {
        // not part of sub-tree: away with it!
        unset( $sorted_menu_items[$key] );
      }
    }

    return $sorted_menu_items;
  } else {
    return $sorted_menu_items;
  }
}
```

Usage

```
wp_nav_menu( array(
  'menu'     => 'Menu Name',
  'sub_menu' => true
) );
```